# How to extract desired field from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

In the below-nested dictionary, I want term present in "fields" value in "field_name" string.

```
response = {
  "indices": [
    "device",
  ],
  "fields": {
    "hostname": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "searchable": true,
        "aggregatable": false
      }
    }
    }
    }
```

My code-

```
    for field in response['fields']:
        if field == field_name:
            print(field)
            d_type= response["fields"][field_name]["text"]["type"]
            print(d_type)
```

Error-

```
d_type= response["fields"][field_name]["text"]["type"]
KeyError: 'text
```

Expected Output-

```
fieldname=hostname
d_type=text
```

Comment: " I want to extract the term from "fields" as "hostname"" - Sorry, but I can't understand what you mean. Please provide your exact expected output in order to clarify.

Comment: OK, but you still didn't provide your expected output. Please do!

Comment: Are you looking to do something like `response["fields"][field_name]["text"]["type"]`?

Comment: I am able to extract field name == hostname by below code.

```
 for field in response['fields']:
        if field == field_name:
            print(field)
```

I am unable to extract d_type as text:

Code error-

```
d_type= response["fields"][field_name]["text"]["type"]
KeyError: 'text'
```

Comment: if it is the case that the key "text" might not be present then: `response["fields"][field_name].get("text", {}).get("type")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
field_name = 'hostname'
for field in response['fields']:
    if field == field_name:
        d_type = response['fields'][field]['text']['type']
print('field=' + field_name)
print('d_type=' + d_type)
```

`field` - key of dictionary

If `field_name` is 'hostname', then `response['fields'][field]` inside loop get dictionary:

```
"text": {
   "type": "text",
   "searchable": True,
   "aggregatable": False
}
```

Comment: yes , i want fieldname is "hostname", can you share complete code for this

Comment: `response['fields']` is a dictionary and if you know `field_name` Why not use it as `d_type = response['fields'][field_name]['esTypes']`

Comment: I suppose, that dictionary can have several dictionaries, and one of them have key `hostname`

Comment: d_type = response['fields'][field_name]['text']['type']

this worked, @JonSG... Thanks